# node-handle vs std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17, unique-ptr, unordered-map, stdmap

Reading the documentation of the node-handle, I noticed that many features of the node-handle type can simply be emulated by a specialization of the `std::unique_ptr`. Indeed, the functionalities of the node-handle type are very similar to the that of the `std::unique_ptr`. It has only an interface more compliant with the features of associative containers, such as the `key_type` and `mapped_type` aliases and the functions to get a reference of the key/mapped value.

Are there any other advantages therefore the standard had introduced a node-handle type over a simple specialization of `std::unique_ptr` as `node_type`?

Comment: Can you provide a link for 'the documentation of the node-handle' ?

Comment: @PeterHull I'd assume the [standard node handle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle)...

Comment: "a simple specialization of std::unique_ptr" wouldn't be conformant to the specification. It would play havoc with traits and overload resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a purely philosophical perspective, just because a type has a similar interface to another type does not mean that the type is redundant and should be replaced by the more general one.

In this particular case, the types are just not equivalent. One of the main goals of `node_handle` is that you don't get to know the actual type of the node being used by the container. Not even as an opaque type alias; `node_type` is a specialization of `node_handle`, not the internal node typename.

Also, consider that `unique_ptr`, by its nature, wraps a pointer to something. There is a pointer that was not owned at some point, then the `unique_ptr` owns it. Therefore, `release` is a reasonable function: it disowns the pointer without destroying it.

That's not a reasonable function for `node_handle`. You did not create that node, and therefore you're not equipped to destroy it. That node is owned by a system that is intentionally opaque to the user. Any pointer held by it points to implementation-defined data structures, and there may be more than one of them.

But that ignores the key feature of `node_handle`, the reason why it exists at all. The point of a `node_handle` is that you can extract an element from such a container, *modify its key* (and thus affecting where it would go in the container), and then reinsert it without allocating memory. To do that with `unique_ptr<T>` would require that `T` be some type the user understands and can talk to (and therefore used to modify the key). So, what is `T`?

It can't be `value_type` for the container, as that makes the key type `const` and therefore non-modifiable. So it has to be some new type that gives you an interface to modify the key's value. Since it has to be some new type anyway... you may as well just make `node_handle` that type and save yourself a bunch of pain.

Also, there is allocator behavior to consider. First, a `node_handle` also stores a copy of the container's allocator. Which `unique_ptr` can't really do.

Second, stateful allocators may have special behavior when you move-assign from one container to another. Specifically, you may need to move the allocator when you do. But for many allocators, you may not. Therefore, `node_handle` needs to replicate this behavior. `unique_ptr` can't do that either.

Now, you could essentially achieve all of this by creating a specialization of `unique_ptr` with a different interface conforming to the above, through the use of hidden (container-specific) typenames as template parameters. But... why bother? It's a different interface with a different, specialized purpose.

So give it its own typename already. C++ is not running out of names.

Comment: Nice answer! However, the paragraph "it can't be value_type for the container, as that makes the key type const and therefore non-modifiable" is not correct, because neither `std::set` nor `std::map` define the `value_type` as const.

Comment: @LoS: I didn't say that they define the `value_type` as `const`. I said "key type". In the case of `map`, the `value_type` is a `pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`. And `set`'s iterators offers no mechanism to modify its `value_type`.